# Structure database for timeline with different objects

Tags: database-design, sql-server, efcore

I need to work on a project where we have a "case". Within this case we need to attach different things, in a timeline.

Those things can be:

- Status change (Open, On hold, Closed)
- Messages (just text)
- Calls (call history, "call lasted x seconds")
- Call rating

Now I don't really have a way of storing this in a MS SQL database. We are using EF Core for `net5.0`.

How do I make a database structure that has different tables all linked in one timeline?
I'm struggling with my data layer.

Example:

```
10:12 AM - Pete wrote: "Foo bar"

10:14 AM - Pete called John, call lasted x seconds. Click here to view the call.

10:14 AM - John rated the call x x x 0 0. (three stars visualized)

11:12 AM - Pete put this case on hold.

11:14 AM - John wrote "ABC"

11:15 AM - John closed this case
```

This is the "timeline" for a case in text. But ofcourse in the actual front-end we'll show a thumbnail of the video call. And we'll show a status change in color. And we'll show actual stars instead of writing `x x x 0 0` .

I don't expect an answer where my program is realized. But could you point me in the right direction so that this is expandable with new tables in the future.

Comment: If the only thing these events have in common is that they are all timestamped; it may be overengineering to try and mash them all into a single table (or highly correlated set of tables), as opposed to simply adding a timestamp column to all of your individual tables and merging these items at a later stage (in-memory, in-UI, ...). It all depends on the size and scope of the solution you want, which isn't quite clear.

Comment: Maybe to put it more elegantly: why are you set on having the database contain the constructed timeline; as opposed to composing the timeline based on much looser (but timestamped) data sets?

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like events with associated data depending on event type.

So the main `EVENT` table could have fields `ID`, `TYPE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `CASE_ID`, `ORIGINATOR`, and a few auxiliary fields (such as `TEXT`, `DURATION`, `RATING` etc.) that could be used in different event types.

For status changes, you would have to decide whether there's a generic event type "StatusChange" and the new status is represented in the `TEXT` field, or there are different event types for the different possible status values.

Associated data that's not easily represented in an auxiliary field would reside in additional tables or even outside the database (you would probably not store media such as video recordings or even thumbnails in the database.) If additional tables are used, you might connect them to the respective events through an `EVENT_ID` foreign key field. For external media, it would be more fitting to have a `MEDIA_URL` field in the main `EVENT` table, and a `THUMBNAIL_URL` field for thumbnails to be shown in the UI.

Comment: So I would fit everything in one table, and depending on the type a lot of columns would be null? I thought of this approach but it didn't feel right. But I guess I could make it seperate classes through EF Core's inheritance and store everything in one table. So my models are different classes, but data is stored in on table.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that springs to mind is a view that `UNION`s the relevant information from each `thing` table into a summary text, a case id, maybe a `thing` type, a timespan and whatnot. You can then index the view on case id and timespan and you got your timeline.

One of the advantages of this is that `things` can have their own tables, normalized as you see fit.

One possible downside to this is that whenever you have changes to the structure of a `thing` (add/remove/rename columns, add/remove `thing` tables) you will have to update the view.